# Change a CSS Property when Audio is done playing

Tags: javascript, audio

I am in the process of creating an Alternate Tuning Web App that espouses alternate tunings for a keyboard! Anyways, I'm trying to get the CSS to change when audio is done playing. I'm trying to create a function that checks if the audio is playing, and if not, change the CSS to have no drop shadow. Ideally, after 30 seconds, the audio stops and the key returns to the "un-pressed" style.

with the keylight function, I've tried...

if (audio1.currentTime == 29) {

if (audio1.currentTime == 30) {

if (audio1.currentTime == 0) {

if (audio1.playing) {

In the full code, I have twelve keys, but here is one of them:

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:black;}
#play432 {
  background-color:#ff4b00;
}
.key {
  color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: -1px 75% 0% 0%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .1s;
}
</style>
<script>
    function play432() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audioA');
        var key = document.getElementById("play432");
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
    }
    function keylight () {
      var audio1 = document.getElementById('audioA');
        var key8 = document.getElementById('play432');
        if (audio1.currentTime == 0) {
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else{
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(keylight(),1000)">
<h3 style="color:white;">Perfect 5th Interval Scale</h3>
<audio src="https://webdevgeometrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/432hz.ogg" id="audioA"></audio>
<div id="play432" onclick="play432()" class="key">A 432 Hz</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) event.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The ended event only fires if the audio has `fully` ended, not when it is paused

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries The OP stated: *I'm trying to get the CSS to change when audio is done playing.* To me, that means when it is fully ended.

Comment: @ScottMarcus :-) add -  *I'm trying to create a function that checks if the audio is playing, and if not, change the CSS to have no drop shadow* - in and it becomes *ended* + *paused*? just saying...

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries I don't see how paused gets added to the mix. But, that's why I added a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[HTMLMediaElement.paused](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused)** property to check if the media is paused or not

```
if (audio1.paused) {
    key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    key8.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:black;}
#play432 {
  background-color:#ff4b00;
}
.key {
  color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: -1px 75% 0% 0%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .1s;
}
</style>
<script>
    function play432() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audioA');
        var key = document.getElementById("play432");
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
    }
    function keylight () {
      var audio1 = document.getElementById('audioA');
        var key8 = document.getElementById('play432');
        if (audio1.paused) {
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else{
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(keylight,1000)">
<h3 style="color:white;">Perfect 5th Interval Scale</h3>
<audio src="https://webdevgeometrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/432hz.ogg" id="audioA"></audio>
<div id="play432" onclick="play432()" class="key">A 432 Hz</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was able to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `.onpause` event:

*The below function removes the drop shadow if the music is paused or done playing.*

```js
   
   var audio = document.getElementById('audioA');
   var key = document.getElementById("play432");
   
   
   function play432() {   
        
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            key.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
    }
    function keylight () {
      var audio1 = document.getElementById('audioA');
        var key8 = document.getElementById('play432');
        if (audio1.currentTime == 0) {
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        }
        else{
            key8.style.boxShadow = "inset 3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            key8.style.textShadow = "3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
            }
        }
     
     
     audio.onpause = function() {
        key.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            key.style.textShadow = "0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
     };
```

```css
body {background-color:black;}
#play432 {
  background-color:#ff4b00;
}
.key {
  color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: -1px 75% 0% 0%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(keylight(),1000)">
<h3 style="color:white;">Perfect 5th Interval Scale</h3>
<audio src="https://webdevgeometrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/432hz.ogg" id="audioA"></audio>
<div id="play432" onclick="play432()" class="key">A 432 Hz</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this into the actual code.